# Show that $x_n$ converges if $x_n+\frac2{x_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${x_n}$ be a sequence with $x_n\ge 1$ for all natural numbers $n$. Then let a sequence $y_n=x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}$ for all $n$. If ${y_n}$ converges, show that ${x_n}$ converges.
I don't know how to do it, so  give me a little clue for this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This will be true under a stronger assumption, e.g. $x_n > \sqrt{2}$ for all $n$. As it is, your statement is false.

A counter-example:
$$
x_n = \begin{cases} 1&\text{ if } n \text { is even}\\
2&\text{ if } n \text { is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $y_{2n} = x_{2n} + \frac{2}{x_{2n}} = 1 + \frac{2}{1} = 3$ and $y_{2n+1} = x_{2n+1} + \frac{2}{x_{2n+1}} = 2 + \frac{2}{2} = 3$, so $(y_n)_n$ converges. But $(x_n)_n$ does not.

---

**A possibility under the stronger assumption:** solve the quadratic equation.

You get that, for all $n\geq 0$,
$$
x_n^2-x_ny_n+2 = 0$$
whose solutions are $\frac{y_n\pm\sqrt{y_n^2-8}}{2}$.

Since $x_n > \sqrt{2}$ for all $n$, this leads to discarding one root, and thus
$$
x_n = \frac{y_n+\sqrt{y_n^2-8}}{2}
$$
but if $(y_n)_n$ converges, the RHS has a limit by continuity, and therefore $(x_n)_n$ converges.

Comment: Yes, my bad ! But in this case it applies to you too. How do you show that $x_n$ is exactly the second root.

Comment: @Svetoslav You are right, the way I handwaved the problem was wrong. It turns out that there is a reason for that: if I'm not mistaken, the *statement asked in the problem* is false.

Comment: (as for the assumption about $\sqrt{2}$: if we assume $1 \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{2}$ for all $n$, then the other root can be discarded and the statement also holds. )

Comment: Yes, this is right. The assumption should be refined. I return you the one point that I took from you :)

Comment: Thank you :) (and sorry for the confusion -- I should have doublechecked my own answer)